# Проблема в ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

Не выводится значение ng-switch, в чем может быть проблема?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title>HomeWork #3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.items = [
                    {
                        question: "Question 1",
                        answer: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
                    },
                    {
                        question: "Question 2",
                        answer: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
                    },
                ];


            })
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="ui container">
        <h1>HomeWork #3</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="ui radio checkbox">
            <input ng-model="number" value="{{$index}}" name="radio" type="radio">
            <label>{{item.question}}</label>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch on="number">
            <div ng-switch-when="0">
                1
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="1">
                2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том, что `ng-repeat` создает свой собственный скоп. Поэтому при использовании `ng-model="number"` переменная `number` будет создана в скопе `ng-repeat`, и к ней не будет доступа вне ее.

Обычное решение - использовать *dot rule*, гласящее, что в выражении используемом в директиве `ng-model` должна быть точка.

Например так:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      question: "Question 1",
      answer: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }, {
      question: "Question 2",
      answer: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }, ];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as c">
    <div class="ui container">
      <h1>HomeWork #3</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="ui radio checkbox">
        <input ng-model="c.number" value="{{$index}}" name="radio" type="radio">
        <label>{{item.question}}</label>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch on="c.number">
        <div ng-switch-when="0">
          1
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="1">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```